# mysql - count status for each user by selecting their name

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I have a table that contains a student name and current date and time and their status like this

> John have 3 day absent
>
> Jane have 2 day absent

I have this code but it counting all absent not for specific user so I'd like to show only John absent day and jane absent day if I select it in a drop down menu

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT student_name, count(status) as numberOfabsent FROM attendance WHERE status = 'Absent' GROUP BY student_name";
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) 
        echo $row['numberOfabsent'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps add a having clause at the end as `having student_name in ('John','jane')` or in the where condition.

Comment: Maybe `SELECT student_name, count(*) as numberOfabsent...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
             $sql = "SELECT *, count(status) as numberOfabsent FROM attendance WHERE status = 'Absent' GROUP BY student_name";
             $result = $db->prepare($sql);
             $result->execute();
             while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
             $numberOfabsent = $row['numberOfabsent'];
             $absdate = $row['timestamp'];
             echo "<tr><td><a href='" . $configs->getConfig('WEB_ROOT') . "admin/adminuseredit.php?usertoedit=" . $row['student_name'] . "'>" . $row['student_name'] . "</a></td>"
             . "<td><div class='shorten'><a href='" . $row['numberOfabsent'] . "'>" . $numberOfabsent  . " days</a></div></td><td>" . $absdate . "</td>"
             . "<td class='text-center'><div class='btn-group btn-group-xs'><a href='".$configs->getConfig('WEB_ROOT')."admin/adminuseredit.php?usertoedit=".$row['student_name']."' title='Edit' class='open_modal btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> View</a>";
             echo"</tr>";
             }
     ?>
```